# vbscript/asp msxml.xmlhttp.6.0 Error Only on First Try

Tags: asp-classic, vbscript, xmlhttprequest

I have asp/vbscript code that posts an XML body to a web api, and received back an XML response.

In a browser, (new session) on the first load, it errors out, and this is the message:

err.source = msxml6.dll, err.number = -2146697208 - The download of the specified resource has failed.

On reloading the page, it works, and it works every single time after that until the session times out.

What could be happening here?

The Code is below - fairly standard.

```
Dim oXmlHttp : Set oXmlHttp = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP.6.0")

On Error Resume Next
oXmlHttp.Open "POST", sUri, False
oXmlHttp.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
oXmlHttp.Send(sRequest)
If Err Then
    response.write "err.source = " & err.Source & ", err.number = " & err.number & " - [" & err.Description & "]"
End If
On Error Goto 0
```

Answer (score 0):

The first thing you should do is stop using XMLHTTP and use ServerXMLHTTP instead.  The XMLHTTP is not safe for use in the server context.